# Elm: Type alias for JSON with "type" property

Tags: elm

I have some JSON with a "type" property that I want to import into Elm. e.g., `{ "id": "abc", "type": "thing" }` However if I define a type alias with `type` as a property, the compiler complains. e.g.,

```
type alias Foo = {
      id: String
    , type: String
}
```

produces

```
It looks like the keyword `type` is being used as a variable.

3│     , type: String
              ^
Rename it to something else.
```

Seriously? I have to rename the property? Is there no way to quote or escape it so it will compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `type` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a field name in a record.

In Elm and Haskell, the most common thing to do in your case seems to be to append a single quote, so it becomes `type'`, and your type definition becomes

```elm
type alias Foo =
  { id: String
  , type': String
  }
```

This has its origin in the [prime symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) from mathematics. It may look odd at first but it is valid syntax.

You can then use the following Json Decoder to translate the JSON into Foo:

```elm
fooDecoder =
  Json.object2
    Foo
    ("id" := Json.string)
    ("type" := Json.string)
```

Notice that the exact field name in Elm does not need to match the JSON field name.

Rarely will you find a language that lets you use keywords as variable names unescaped. This behavior is not unique to Elm.

Comment: Appending a single quote does not escape the field name, though, it changes it to a different name.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how the field name in JSON does not need to match the Elm field it gets decoded to.

Comment: Using a single quote in the name goes really wrong in Elm 0.16 at least. It becomes the start of a string literal in generated JS. Using _ instead works well.

Comment: @AlexKorban - I haven't had a problem in Elm 0.16. Defining this `foo'bar' = "asdf"` works just fine.

Comment: I run into `Ran into a single quote in a variable name. This was removed in 0.18!` error with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can now escape the keyword with an underscore.

ex.

```
type alias Foo =
  { id: String
  , type_: String
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In oscpad, I'm using a "type" field in my json interface over websockets.  But I don't have a field called type in an elm record.  I just look for a "type" field when I'm parsing JSON.  My code looks like this:

```
jsSpec : JD.Decoder Spec
jsSpec =
  ("type" := JD.string) `JD.andThen` jsCs

jsCs : String -> JD.Decoder Spec
jsCs t =
  case t of
    "button" -> SvgButton.jsSpec `JD.andThen` (\a -> JD.succeed (CsButton a))
    "slider" -> SvgSlider.jsSpec `JD.andThen` (\a -> JD.succeed (CsSlider a))
    "label" -> SvgLabel.jsSpec `JD.andThen` (\a -> JD.succeed (CsLabel a))
    "sizer" -> jsSzSpec `JD.andThen` (\a -> JD.succeed (CsSizer a))
    _ -> JD.fail ("unkown type: " ++ t)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no escape. Elm is uncompromising.

Comment: kind of a harsh behaviour. What if someone is working with an API which he doesn't control?

Comment: @marcosh well you can translate the keyword to another field/varable name, and that name is only used within Elm. If you export to JS via a port, you'll have to encode it back. So the field name wont match the JSON property name exactly, but it's not a barrier to working with any sort of JSON. Just annoying IMO